# I need the Windows user id apache 2.4 / PHP

Tags: php, windows, apache, authentication

I am running a php8 application (with Apache 2.4 as the web server) on a Windows server.  I want to extract the windows user id of the web page user.  In my organization the user id is not a secret.  Everybody knows (or can easily find) everybody else's.  Everyone is on the same domain as the web server.  I am looking to avoid making the user type their password (a security risk from our perspective), and I don't want to initiate a new authentication protocol.

In IIS / aspx / c# this is simple:  You use HttpContext.  Is there something similar I can use in my environment?

Answer (score 2):

This is not as simple as with IIS/C#, but you can use the [Apache Kerberos Authentication module](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/). With PHP, you can then get the user's information from:

```php
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']
$_SERVER['KRB5CCNAME']
```

Relevant article: https://imatviyenko.github.io/blog/2018/09/11/Apache-AD-kerberos

Comment: Holy configuration, batman!  Thanks for the pointer, Itay.  It will take me some time to absorb that.